# Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo' because it does not exist

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute following commands to clear files in a temporary directory. If there are multiple files for a particular day I should keep only the latest file.

```
$groups = get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Temp\Archive" -Filter "*_bak.zip" | ?{-not $_.PsIsContainer} | Group {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}

if($groups -ne $NULL){
    ForEach ($files in $groups) {
        "Count: $($files.Count)"
        if ($files.Count -gt 1) { 
            $files | Sort LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First ($files.Count - 1) | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
        }
    }
}
```

But, I'm getting the following error. I'm executing these commands as an administrator. And, Execution Policy is set to Unrestricted.

**Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo' because it does not exist.
At D:\User1\Tasks\Delete_backup_files.ps1:86 char:87
+             $files | Sort LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First ($files.Count - 1) | Remove-Item <<<<  -Force -WhatIf
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\syst...mands.GroupInfo:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand**

The `Remove-Item` command works fine if I just use it with a UNC path.

`$files.FullName` doesn't have a value. I suspect this could be the issue. But, I'm not sure how to fix it. I need the grouping logic to stay as is.

I hope someone could help me out here.

Thanks!

Comment: It's actually a good thing it failed to delete files under system32!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually very close. You have to pass the files within the group to the `sort` command, not the group itself:

```
$files.Group | Sort LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First ($files.Count - 1) | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

The error you get:

> Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo' because it does not exist.

Happens because `Remove-Item` requires a string as input. But you are passing a `GroupInfo` object so PS calls the `ToString()` method. `Remove-Item` interprets the resulting string as a file name located in your current location `C:\WINDOWS\system32\`.